# I got this problem with animating, when I switch frames, the pose of reverts

Tags: animation, keyframes, pose-mode

So I have the problem where I'm making an animation of a character walking after making one of them in idle pose. The first animation was easy, but now that I am trying to make the walking onwe I have run into a problem I can't figure out how to solve. Basically I made the beginning pose on frame zero and make a key frame of it. Then I moved to frame 20 and made a new pose and key framed it. However if I moved to a different frame and then back to twenty the pose has reverted back to the one from frame zero. Though the key frames I made still register on frame twenty on the dope sheet they have reverted.

Here is my blend file, since every time I ask a question is ends in my having to upload it anyway.
blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6006

Comment: Please show you work as a Blender screen capture .  I am aware you may have attempted a file inclusion.  It may be unnecessary to open the file.

Comment: Your file include, if you attempted one, is not working in the standard fashion.

Comment: Ya I messed up the link code, just copy and paste it into the address bar, it works that way I tested it.

Comment: I have the same problem I have no idea how to delete the cache, I can't create new animations because all poses revert back to another animation no matter how many times I saved the frames

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is weird, I inadvertently solved the problem, it was apparently a glitch after all. What I did was changed the timeline to the idle animation to make sure it wasn't messed up too. And when I changed back to the timeline of the messed up animation it was working properly all of a sudden. To think I wasted a weak not getting my project done because of this problem and that was all I had to do.

Comment: I do believe Blender has these lapses of sanity once in a great while. I tend to see that during Particle work.  I have no not seen or do not remember your pose issue.

Comment: week or weak?  spelling correction perhaps.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger  is right!  When these inexplicable glitches occur I find the cure is often in saving the file to another filename, exit Blender altogether, delete any cache files it makes, (usually in the current project folder) and also any quit and other files in Blender's temp folder. (as setup in User Pref's)  Reload your new Blend file .

Comment: Can you go farther into explaining how to delete the file caches and the the blender temp folder?? I tried to figure it out myself but I couldn't and did find an answer on the net?